# How can I join RDD[Rating] with scala.collection.Map[Int, Double] by key column?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dictionary, rdd

I have two table ->

> table1: RDD[Rating] (rdd1,rdd2,rdd3)

and

> table2: scala.collection.Map[Int, Double] (m1,m2)

I spent a lot of time and effort trying to make joined table like

> (key (key = rdd2 = m1), rdd3, m2)

But I always have a type mismatch.

Could you give an advice how to deal with it? I also try to convert both table to one type, but I'm note sure is t right way...

Answer (score 0):

Based on you have an `RDD` and a `Map`, you can do it directly iterating your `RDD`.

Assuming that `Rating` has 3 fields (rdd1,rdd2,rdd3), let's rename them as `field1`, `field2` and `field3` to make the example clear and avoid confusions.

Giving this sample input source:

```
case class Rating(field1: String, field2: Int, field3: String) // custom case class
val yourRDD = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(
  Seq(
    Rating("rating1", 1, "str1"), // item 1
    Rating("rating2", 2, "str2"), // item 2
    Rating("rating3", 3, "str3")  // item 3
  )
)
yourRDD.toDF.show() // to visualize()
```

this will output your data source, that will look like:

```
+-------+------+------+
| field1|field2|field3|
+-------+------+------+
|rating1|     1|  str1|
|rating2|     2|  str2|
|rating3|     3|  str3|
+-------+------+------+
```

Similarly, you have this sample data for your map:

```
val yourMap = Map(
  1 -> 1.111,
  2 -> 2.222,
  3 -> 3.333
)
println(yourMap)
```

Data on your map:

```
yourMap: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,Double] = Map(1 -> 1.111, 2 -> 2.222, 3 -> 3.333)
```

Then, to "merge" you only need to iterate your `RDD`, get the value that you are going to use as `key`, in this case `field2` and use it as `key` for the `map`. Something like this:

```
yourRDD
  .map(rating=>{ // iterate each item in your RDD
    val key = rating.field2 // get the value from the current item
    val valueFromMap = yourMap(key) // look for the value on the map using field2 as key - You need to handle null values in case that you wont have values for all the keys

    (key, rating.field3, valueFromMap) // generating an output for a new RDD that will be created based on this
}).toDF.show(truncate=false) // visualize the output
```

Above code will output:

```
+---+----+-----+
|_1 |_2  |_3   |
+---+----+-----+
|1  |str1|1.111|
|2  |str2|2.222|
|3  |str3|3.333|
+---+----+-----+
```

Hope this could help